# Algorithm to generate a subset in order of its sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

I am interested in an algorithm which can generate or order the subsets of some set in order of increasing sum. I have reviewed some similar questions but they only talk about generating subsets in linear order, like [Algorithm to generate k element subsets in order of their sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125524/algorithm-to-generate-k-element-subsets-in-order-of-their-sum) and [Algorithm wanted: Enumerate all subsets of a set in order of increasing sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89419/algorithm-wanted-enumerate-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-order-of-increasing-sums)

Is there a clever way of doing this in faster time?

I previously tried generating an interval tree from all subsets and then searching along that, where the root node is the rightmost integer in the set, the left node moves the leftmost integer down one, and the right node appends the next greatest integer. So `{1,3,5,8}` is

```
                                8
            5                                  5,8
  3                  3,5              3,8                3,5,8
1   1,3          1,5     1,3,5    1,8     1,3,8    1,5,8       1,3,5,8
```

At any node, the left interval will be the smallest value in the subset replaced with the smallest value in the set to the left node's subset with all elements to the left of the largest element in this left node's subset included. The right interval is the same logic but mirrored. If the target sum is not in one of the intervals, then don't search the subtree. If it's in both subtrees, then search both. This can be done virtually where the range can be retrieved without having to generate any subtrees, so it doesn't require actually building the tree, just each node at each step. This method seemed to work in the average case, but is exponential in the worst case.

Are there any approaches along these lines?

Comment: Any algorithm will take exponential time: there's 2^n subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your interval tree example and answers linked, it sounds as though you want to generate the `k-th` largest subset without generating prior subsets and doing so in time less than `O(k)`, if I'm understanding correctly, as you mentioned wanting something faster than the previous linear approaches. A solution to this would prove that [P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), since you could do a binary search over all subsets by generating each `k-th` largest subset in sub-exponential time.

I played around with this problem years ago, trying to generate the `k-th` largest subset in sum order to then do a binary search over the subsets in order of their sum, so perhaps I can try to explain a fundamental issue with this approach, namely that certain groups of subsets are inherently incomparable, and the number of incomparable subsets that must be compared in the worst case grows exponentially as the input size grew.

The search space for the subset sum problem is the power set of the input set. More specifically, the search space is the sum of each subset of the power set of the input set. For example, for the input set `{1, 2, 3}`, the search space is `{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}`, or simply, `{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6}`. Regardless of the input set, the least subset sum will always be the singleton of the first element, the next least subset sum will always be the singleton of the second element, and the next least subset sum will always be the subset of the first two elements of the input set. Similarly, the greatest subset sum will always be the sum of the input set in its entirety, while the next greatest subset sum will always be the sum of the input set sans the first element, the next greatest subset sum will always be the sum of the input set sans the second element, and the next greatest subset sum will always be the sum of the input set sans the first and second elements.

But going back to the previous input set `{1, 2, 3}`, what about an input set of the same size such as `{1, 2, 2}`? The search space becomes `{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}`, or `{1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6}`. If you are trying to order the power set in order of its sum for a set `{a, b, c}`, then you must compare `{a, b}` and `{c}`, since there are input sets in which `{a, b}` is greater and others where `{c}` is greater. The two subsets are incomparable. If you could guarantee that one was always greater than the other, then you could design a search algorithm appropriately, but you do not, so you will have to check these two elements at the very least.

For an input set of size 4 `{a, b, c, d}`, there are also two incomparable subsets: `{a, d}` and `{b, c}`; compare the sums of these subsets for `{1, 2, 4, 8}` and `{1, 3, 3, 3}`. In fact, there are a few other groups of dually incomparable subsets, such as `{a, b, c}` and `{b, d}`. If we draw a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of this, we get (apologies for the ASCII art):

```
     a,b,c,d
        |
      b,c,d
        |
      a,c,d--------|
        |          |
      a,b,d---|---c,d
        |     |
      a,b,c  b,d
        |     |
       b,c   a,d
        |     |
       a,c----d
 -------|     |
a,b     c-----|
 |      |
 |------b
        |
        a
```

In other words, you could design an algorithm to do a binary search on the chain of `{{a}, {b}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}, {b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}` and another binary search on the chain of `{{c}, {d}, {a, d}, {b, d}, {c, d}}`, or two binary searches on another configuration of these chains, but ultimately you would have to perform at least two binary searches. You can always guarantee that `a+b <= a+c`, or `b+d <= a+c+d` (as `b+d <= c+d <= a+c+d`), but you cannot guarantee that e.g. `b+c <= a+d`. In the worst case, you would have to make these comparisons.

Taking it a step further, for an input set of size 5 `{a, b, c, d, e}`, the subsets of `{a, d}`, `{b, c}`, and `{e}` are incomparable. For example:

`{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}` has `{b, c} <= {a, d} <= {e}`

`{1, 2, 2, 2, 5}` has `{a, d} <= {b, c} <= {e}`

`{5, 5, 5, 6, 6}` has `{e} <= {b, c} <= {a, d}`

`{1, 5, 5, 6, 6}` has `{e} <= {a, d} <= {b, c}`

`{1, 4, 4, 4, 6}` has `{a, d} <= {e} <= {b, c}`

`{1, 2, 2, 6, 6}` has `{b, c} <= {e} <= {a, d}`

To put together another ASCII Hasse diagram:

```
    a,b,c,d,e
        |
     b,c,d,e
        |
     a,c,d,e-------------------------|
        |                            |
     a,b,d,e-------------------|---c,d,e
        |                      |
     a,b,c,e------------|----b,d,e
        |               |      |
     a,b,c,d          a,d,e  b,c,e
        |               |      |
      b,c,d            d,e   a,c,e
        |               |      |
      a,c,d--------|---c,e-----|---a,b,e
        |          |    |            |
      a,b,d---|---c,d  b,e-----------|
        |     |         |
      a,b,c  b,d     --a,e
        |     |     /   |
       b,c  -a,d---/    e
        |  /  |         |
       a,c    d---------|
 -------|     |
a,b     c-----|
 |      |
 |------b
        |
        a
```

In the worst case, you would have to do three binary searches, as the largest grouping of incomparable sets is three.

There is a pattern here. The sum of the subsets form a partial order. For sets of size 3, the width (also known as the [maximum antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain)) of this partial order is 2. For size 4, it is also 2. For size 5, the width is 3. For sets of size 6, the width is 5. For size 7, the width is 8. For size 8, the width is 14. For size 9, the width is 23. For size 10, the width is 40. For size 11, the width is 70.

In fact, this sequence of integers is known. It's in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences A025591](https://oeis.org/A025591) as the number of solutions to +- 1 +- 2 +- 3 +- ... +- n = 0 or 1. This integer sequence has also been discussed in [Robert A. Proctor's 1982 paper "Solution of Two Difficult Combinatorial Problems with Linear Algebra,"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975833) in which the problem of finding a set of n distinct positive real numbers with as large a collection as possible of subsets with the same sum is shown to be the first n positive integers: `{1,2,...,n}`. Proctor gave the first elementary proof of this result requiring no more than a background in linear algebra to follow. The maximal numbers of subsets of `{1,2,...,n}` having the same sum for `n=1, 2, ...` are 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 14, 23, etc, or [OEIS A025591](https://oeis.org/A025591), the same integer sequence discussed above. In fact, this sequence was constructed in the paper in the same manner that was discussed above.

Going back to the problem of identifying comparable subsets, this ordering can be generalized to account for all subsets of an input set by three cases. Given two subsets `A` and `B` of any input set `S`:

1. Consider the case where the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of `A` is greater than the cardinality of `B`. Then it cannot be guaranteed that the sum of `B` is greater than the sum of `A`.
2. Consider the case where the cardinality of `A` is equal to the cardinality of `B`. For each element `A[i]` and `B[i]` from `i=0 to cardinality(A)`, if the index in `S` from which `A[i]` was drawn is greater than the index in `S` from which `B[i]` was drawn, then it cannot be guaranteed that the sum of `B` is greater than the sum of `A`. Otherwise, it can be guaranteed that the sum of `B` is greater than the sum of `A`.
3. Consider the case where the cardinality of `A` is less than the cardinality of `B`. Remove the least elements of the set `B` such that the cardinality of `A` and `B` are equal. The second case may now be applied.

To help illustrate this, I threw together some code which builds a directed acyclic graph from the power set of an input set in which each edge connects a node with a lesser subset sum to all nodes with a greater subset sum. This process forms a transitive closure, as all lesser nodes will be connected to all greater nodes. The transitive reduction is then applied to this graph, and the size of the maximum antichain is returned along with the subsets which make up this antichain, formatted as `[index, value]`, by walking up the Hasse diagram and storing the width at each level. The final graph will have a maximum antichain equal to the integer sequence [A025591](https://oeis.org/A025591).

(This code was quickly thrown together to demonstrate what I am trying to say. I apologize in advance for any poor coding decisions made!)

```
import com.google.common.graph.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AntichainDecomposition {
  MutableGraph<Subset> graph;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Input set. Modify this as needed.
    int[] set = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    ArrayList<Subset> input = buildSubsets(set);
    AntichainDecomposition antichain = new AntichainDecomposition(input);
  }

  public AntichainDecomposition(ArrayList<Subset> input) {
    graph = GraphBuilder.directed().build();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
      graph.addNode(input.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); ++j) {
        if (i != j && isTargetGreater(input.get(i), input.get(j))) {
          graph.putEdge(input.get(i), input.get(j));
        }
      }
    }
    graphReduction();
    int width = getWidth(input.get(input.size() / 2));
    System.err.println(width);
  }

  private int getWidth(Subset first) {
    HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Subset>> levelMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Subset>>();
    HashMap<Subset, Integer> subsetToLevel = new HashMap<Subset, Integer>();
    int level = 1;

    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    HashMap<Subset, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<Subset, Boolean>();
    Iterator iter = graph.nodes().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Subset node = (Subset)iter.next();
      visited.put(node, false);
    }

    // Create a queue for breadth first search
    LinkedList<Subset> queue = new LinkedList<Subset>();

    // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
    levelMap.put(level, new HashSet<Subset>());
    levelMap.get(level).add(first);
    subsetToLevel.put(first, level);
    visited.put(first, true);
    queue.add(first);

    while (queue.size() != 0) {
      // Dequeue a vertex from the queue and store it in the appropriate level
      Subset s = queue.poll();
      level = subsetToLevel.get(s);

      // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
      // If a successor has not been visited, then mark it
      // visited and enqueue it
      iter = graph.successors(s).iterator();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Subset n = (Subset)iter.next();
        if (!visited.get(n)) {
          if (!levelMap.containsKey(level + 1)) {
            levelMap.put(level + 1, new HashSet<Subset>());
          }
          levelMap.get(level + 1).add(n);
          subsetToLevel.put(n, level + 1);
          visited.put(n, true);
          queue.add(n);
        }
      }
    }

    int width = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    iter = levelMap.values().iterator();
    Iterator subsetIter = null;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      HashSet<Subset> levelSet = (HashSet<Subset>)iter.next();
      if (levelSet.size() > width) {
        width = levelSet.size();
        subsetIter = levelSet.iterator();
      }
    }

    if (subsetIter != null) {
      while (subsetIter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println((Subset)subsetIter.next());
      }
    }

    return width;
  }

  private void graphReduction() {
    // Reflexive reduction
    Iterator iter1 = graph.nodes().iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
      Subset i = (Subset)iter1.next();
      graph.removeEdge(i, i);
    }

    // Transitive reduction
    iter1 = graph.nodes().iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
      Subset j = (Subset)iter1.next();
      Iterator iter2 = graph.nodes().iterator();
      while (iter2.hasNext()) {
        Subset i = (Subset)iter2.next();
        if (graph.removeEdge(i, j)) {
          graph.putEdge(i, j);
          Iterator iter3 = graph.nodes().iterator();
          while (iter3.hasNext()) {
            Subset k = (Subset)iter3.next();
            if (graph.removeEdge(j, k)) {
              graph.putEdge(j, k);
              graph.removeEdge(i, k);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private Stack<Subset> topologicalSort() {
    Stack<Subset> stack = new Stack<Subset>();
    int vertices = graph.nodes().size();

    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    HashMap<Subset, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<Subset, Boolean>();
    Iterator iter = graph.nodes().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Subset node = (Subset)iter.next();
      visited.put(node, false);
    }

    // Call the recursive helper function to store topological sort
    // starting from all vertices one by one
    iter = graph.nodes().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Subset node = (Subset)iter.next();
      if (!visited.containsKey(node) || !visited.get(node)) {
        topologicalSortHelper(node, visited, stack);
      }
    }

    return stack;
  }

  private void topologicalSortHelper(Subset v, HashMap<Subset, Boolean> visited, Stack<Subset> stack) {
    visited.put(v, true);

    // Recurse for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    Iterator iter = graph.successors(v).iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Subset node = (Subset)iter.next();
      if (!visited.containsKey(node) || !visited.get(node)) {
        topologicalSortHelper(node, visited, stack);
      }
    }

    // Push current vertex to stack which stores topological sort
    stack.push(v);
  }

  private boolean isTargetGreater(Subset source, Subset target) {
    // An edge between two nodes exists if each index in the target subset is greater than or
    // equal to its respective index in the source subset. If the target subset size is greater
    // than the source subset size, then an edge between the two subsets exists if and only if
    // the target subset has indices that are greater than or equal to corresponding indices of
    // the source subset, ignoring the additional indices of the target subset.
    if (source.size() > target.size()) {
      return false;
    }
    SubsetEntry[] newSubset = new SubsetEntry[target.size()];
    System.arraycopy(target.getSubset(), 0, newSubset, 0, newSubset.length);
    Subset newTarget = new Subset(Arrays.asList(newSubset).subList(target.size() -
                                                                   source.size(), target.size()).
                                    toArray(new SubsetEntry[source.size()]));
    for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); ++i) {
      if (source.getEntry(i).getIndex() > newTarget.getEntry(i).getIndex()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static ArrayList<Subset> buildSubsets(int[] set) {
    ArrayList<Subset> power = new ArrayList<Subset>();
    int elements = set.length;
    int powerElements = (int) Math.pow(2, elements);
    for (int i = 0; i < powerElements; ++i) {
      // Convert the binary number to a string containing n digits
      String binary = intToBinary(i, elements);

      // Create a new set
      ArrayList<SubsetEntry> innerSet = new ArrayList<SubsetEntry>();

      // Convert each digit in the current binary number to the corresponding element
      // in the given set
      for (int j = 0; j < binary.length(); ++j) {
        if (binary.charAt(j) == '1') {
          innerSet.add(new SubsetEntry(j, set[j]));
        }
      }

      // Add the new set to the power set
      if (!innerSet.isEmpty()) {
        power.add(new Subset(innerSet.toArray(new SubsetEntry[innerSet.size()])));
      }
    }
    return power;
  }

  private static String intToBinary(int binary, int digits) {
    String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(binary);
    int foundDigits = temp.length();
    String returner = temp;
    for (int i = foundDigits; i < digits; ++i) {
      returner = "0" + returner;
    }
    return returner;
  }
}

class SubsetEntry {
  private int index;
  private int value;

  public SubsetEntry(int i, int v) {
    index = i;
    value = v;
  }

  public int getIndex() {
    return index;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "[" + index + ", " + value + "]";
  }
}

class Subset {
  private SubsetEntry[] entries;

  public Subset(SubsetEntry[] e) {
    entries = new SubsetEntry[e.length];
    System.arraycopy(e, 0, entries, 0, entries.length);
  }

  public void setSubset(SubsetEntry[] subset) {
    entries = new SubsetEntry[subset.length];
    System.arraycopy(subset, 0, entries, 0, subset.length);
  }

  public SubsetEntry[] getSubset() {
    return entries;
  }

  public SubsetEntry getEntry(int index) {
    return entries[index];
  }

  public int size() {
    return entries.length;
  }

  public String toString() {
    String s = "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
      s += entries[i].toString();
    }
    s += "}";
    return s;
  }
}
```

Per [Dilworth's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem), for any partially ordered set, the cardinality of the largest antichain is equal to the minimum number of chains that can be used to cover the partially ordered set. This produces a partial order with [A025591](https://oeis.org/A025591) chains in the worst case for any input set. Further, the worst case time for searching a partial order is `O(w*log(n))`, where w is the width of the graph (equal to the cardinality of the largest antichain). This can be demonstrated by the fact that an antichain is characterized as an unordered list in which no two elements are comparable, and the worst case time for searching an unordered list is `O(n)`. Further, a chain is characterized as an ordered list in which each element is comparable with all other elements in the list, and the worst case time for searching an ordered list is `O(log n)`. Therefore, for each element in the antichain of length `w`, `log(n)` comparisons in the respective chain must be made in the worst case, resulting in a search time of `O(w*log(n))` in the worst case over any partial order.

This partial order search time provides the worst case characterization for the ordering of the sums of each subset of an arbitrary input set. This is due to the fact that, for any input set, each sum in the antichain would need to be observed in order to deduce an optimal search tree. Recall that, using your original set `{1, 3, 5, 8}` as an example, the sum of the subset `{3, 5}` at indices 1 and 2 is less than the sum of the subset `{1, 8}` at indices 0 and 3. However, for the set `{1, 2, 3, 3}`, the sum of the subset `{2, 3}` at indices 1 and 2 is greater than the sum of the subset `{1, 3}` at indices 0 and 3. The sets of indices `{1, 2}` and `{0, 3}` are subsequently incomparable. As the set expands, this order of incomparability grows at an exponential rate as defined in [A025591](https://oeis.org/A025591).

I will close this by saying that I am assuming that all numbers used in the input set are positive and that the input set is sorted. In fact, if you were working with an unsorted list or a mixture of positive and negative numbers, then no two elements are guaranteed to be comparable.

I apologize if this answer is long and rambling, but I hope that this helps provide you with some insight into the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the lengthy, thoughtful answer and clarifications! This helps so much!

Answer (score 2):

If your sets can contain only *positive* integers, then the straightforward way is to use a priority queue, as follows:

1. Add the empty set {} to the queue
2. Remove the set with the smallest sum from the queue and output it
3. Enumerate all the sets that can be created by adding exactly one element to the set you removed, and add them to the queue if they haven't been added before.
4. if the queue isn't empty yet, go back to 2.

This basically uses Dijkstra's algorithm on the graph of subsets, where each set is a vertex and the edges are all the incremental ways to generate new sets that increase the sum.

If you can have negative integers in your set, you can still use a variant of the above.  Just make sure you start with the smallest  possible subset -- the one that contains all the negative numbers, and in step 3 you go through all the incremental ways to make a bigger sum, which means either adding a positive number or removing a negative one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I was aware of such an algorithm and was more  interested if a particular subset could be generated faster.

Comment: Which particular subset?  The one with a specific sum (like the 0-1 knapsack problem)?